# How to find all occurrences of a string within a list when string is only part of the list item

Tags: python, string, find

Using Python I cannot see a way to find instances within a list where the target string is a component (or partial) of a list item. I am looking for any instance of 'Volts' within all of the items in the list, whether volts is a full list item or there is a list item containing volts in some way. The list item could start or end with volts or even have volts contained in it in the middle of the item e.g. voltsOut, loadVolts, allVoltsSettings.

**Code:**

```
data = [ 'Model', 'Name', 'Trans', 'Rx','OnPropertyChanged', 
 'OnPropertyChangedAll', 'OtfMonitorEnabled', 'Overloads', 'PaletteBlackValue', 
 'PaletteSizeFeature', 'PaletteSizeMax', 'PaletteValues', 'PaletteValuesArray', 
 'PowerControlFeature', 'TransVolts','RecVolts', 'PropertyChanged', 'ReferenceEquals', 'Volts']

indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x == "Volts"]
print(indices)
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
I want it to show indices = [14,15,18]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close!

Just use the `in` keyword to check if given string (e.g. "volts") is contained in another string:

```
data = [ 'Model', 'Name', 'Trans', 'Rx','OnPropertyChanged',
 'OnPropertyChangedAll', 'OtfMonitorEnabled', 'Overloads', 'PaletteBlackValue',
 'PaletteSizeFeature', 'PaletteSizeMax', 'PaletteValues', 'PaletteValuesArray',
 'PowerControlFeature', 'TransVolts','RecVolts', 'PropertyChanged', 'ReferenceEquals', 'Volts']

indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if "Volts" in x]
print(indices)
```

Comment: thank you Aviv, I am going to have to learn about enumerate, much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome @Windy71

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this if it is easier to understand

```
data = [ 'Model', 'Name', 'Trans', 'Rx','OnPropertyChanged',
 'OnPropertyChangedAll', 'OtfMonitorEnabled', 'Overloads', 'PaletteBlackValue',
 'PaletteSizeFeature', 'PaletteSizeMax', 'PaletteValues', 'PaletteValuesArray',
 'PowerControlFeature', 'TransVolts','RecVolts', 'PropertyChanged', 'ReferenceEquals', 'Volts']

for i in enumerate(data):
    if 'Volts' in i[1] or 'volts' in i[1]:
        print(i[0])
```

Comment: thank you the case handling is useful too, appreciated.